# Getting the Alt info from PositionedImage inside Docs Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to extract the Alt description from a positionedimage in apps script?

For inline images, you can use the getAltDescription() function

`var captions =inlineimage.getAltDescription();`

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image.html

Comment: Can I ask you about the issue of your script?

Comment: Since positionedImage class doesn't have that method the answer must be no.

Comment: @Tanaike ask away

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is a workaround

You can use the [Advanced Docs Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs) which allows you to access with [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) the [positionedObjects resource](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/PositionedObject) - including the [EmbeddedObject  resource](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/EmbeddedObject) "description".

To retrieve the description with Apps Script:

- [Enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the Advanced Docs Service
- Perform a request with the following syntax:

```
var captions=Docs.Documents.get(fileId).positionedObjects[objectId]["positionedObjectProperties"]["embeddedObject"]["description"];
```

If you do not know `objectId`, you can retrieve it from the JSON response of the request, e.g. (provided you have only one positioned element in your file):

```
var json=JSON.stringify(Docs.Documents.get(fileId).positionedObjects);
var objectId = json.substring(json.indexOf("{") + 2, json.indexOf('":{'));
```